# How can I sort a collection before rendering it in liquid on Dawn/Shopify?

Tags: for-loop, iteration, shopify, liquid

**1. The problem.**

I want to sort sold out products at the bottom of a Shopify collection using liquid, in a customized version of the Dawn theme.

I tried filtering the product loop twice using opposing criteria, and it works to some extent. The main issue is that the pagination renders both loops per page, rather than rendering the whole collection and then paginating it.

So in a collection with 100 products, 30 sold out, and 5 pages with 24 products per page, the goal is for the 30 sold out products to take up pages 4 and 5. With my current code, it only pushes the sold out products in the first 24 spots to the bottom of that page, making the rest of the collection appear sold out when the user scrolls to the bottom.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<div id="CollectionProductGrid">
  {%- paginate collection.products by section.settings.products_per_page -%}
    {%- if collection.products.size == 0 -%}
      <div class="collection collection--empty page-width" id="main-collection-product-grid" data-id="{{ section.id }}">
        <div class="loading-overlay gradient"></div>

        <p class="collection-product-count light" role="status">
          {%- if collection.products_count == collection.all_products_count -%}
            {{ 'sections.collection_template.product_count_simple' | t: count: collection.products_count }}
          {%- else -%}
            {{ 'sections.collection_template.product_count' | t: product_count: collection.products_count, count: collection.all_products_count }}
          {%- endif -%}
        </p>

        <div class="title-wrapper center">
          <h2 class="title title--primary">
            {{ 'sections.collection_template.empty' | t }}<br>
            {{ 'sections.collection_template.use_fewer_filters_html' | t: link: collection.url, class: "underlined-link link" }}
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    {%- else -%}
      <div class="collection page-width">
        <div class="loading-overlay gradient"></div>

        <ul id="main-collection-product-grid" data-id="{{ section.id }}" class="
          grid grid--1-col negative-margin product-grid
          {% if collection.products_count < 4 %} grid--{{ collection.products_count }}-col-tablet{% else %}
            {% if collection.products_count == 4 %} grid--4-col-desktop{% else %} grid--3-col-tablet grid--one-third-max grid--4-col-desktop grid--quarter-max{% endif %}
          {% endif %}">
          {% comment %}--Loops through available products first--{% endcomment %}
          {%- for product in collection.products -%}
          {%- if product.available  -%}
            <li class="grid__item">
              {% render 'product-card',
                product_card_product: product,
                media_size: section.settings.image_ratio,
                show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
                add_image_padding: section.settings.add_image_padding,
                show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
                show_image_outline: section.settings.show_image_outline,
                show_rating: section.settings.show_rating,
                show_atc: section.settings.show_atc
              %}
            </li>
          {%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}
          {%- for product in collection.products -%}
          {%- unless product.available  -%}
            <li class="grid__item">
              {% render 'product-card',
                product_card_product: product,
                media_size: section.settings.image_ratio,
                show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
                add_image_padding: section.settings.add_image_padding,
                show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
                show_image_outline: section.settings.show_image_outline,
                show_rating: section.settings.show_rating,
                show_atc: section.settings.show_atc
              %}
            </li>
          {%- endunless -%}{%- endfor -%}
        </ul>

        {%- if paginate.pages > 1 -%}
          {% render 'pagination', paginate: paginate, anchor: '' %}
        {%- endif -%}
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endpaginate -%}
</div>
```

The issue is the pagination, and it seems to be a difficult one to manipulate for an inexperienced coder like myself, so there are still other options I believe might work.

Either 1: **Sorting**
Creating a custom sorting order, if that is even possible. Since the sorting works with the pagination,  this might be one of the easier ways to achieve this I believe, but I don't know how.

2: **Using the filters and re-rendering the collection with javascript**
This is far from ideal in terms of performance and UX, but might work as a hack since the filters seem to render the collection very quickly in real-time after filtering.

3: **Filtering the loop before rendering it, and before pagination.**
This is what I believe will be the best solution.

I have looked into capturing the loop in an array, but I am struggling to putting it all together correctly. This post explains how you can do this: http://www.codeshopify.com/blog_posts/building-arrays-with-liquid-in-shopify

And here is some example code I believe might be helpful:

```
{% capture products_list %}
  {% for product in collection.products%}
    {{product.title}}|{{product.url}}|{{product.description}}|{{product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}
    {% if forloop.last == false %}::{% endif%}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign products_array = products_list | split: '::'%}
```

What I need help with for the last option, is to figure out what to capture, how to concatinate it properly, and then how to loop through the new and filtered array. Or, a better solution if there is one.

Comment: it's too late to comment here, I got the same issue. Did you get any solution?